# How to: Progress bar in bash

Tags: linux, bash

I want to show a progress bar during a bash operation in a specific format something similar to the following:

```
[###########](40%)
```

after update it should become

```
[###############](50%)
```

and then similarly reach upto `100%`

Is there any way to achieve this

I wrote the following bash program but i don't know how to show the percentage in this on same line:

```
#!/bin/bash
{
    echo -n "["
    for ((i = 0 ; i <= 100 ; i+=6)); do
        sleep 0.05
        echo -n "###"
    done
    echo -n "]"
    echo
}
```

Let's assume that a certain number of operations are being performed in a loop and after the completion of each operation, I want to report some progress. I don't want to install `pv` or any other utilities that does not come with default `Ubuntu 12.04` installation.

Comment: Does it have to be that specific format alone? Will a normal progress bar not work?

Comment: @zmo but in that solution, you will have to write so many `echo` statements, isn't there a better way of doing it. something like echo in a `loop` or something?

Comment: @darnir what other format are you referring to? can you please explain.

Comment: the first answer explains the ASCII trick used to make a progress bar on one line, then the other answers give you different ways to do it. the best way would be to use the `bar` program.

Comment: @dreamer: I wasn't aware of the duplicate question. I was going to point to utilities like `pv` and `bar`.

Comment: though you may feel your solution makes more sense, in that you're only adding new progress from the last progress level in a single loop, your solution is way more maths and `echo`es than the other one. Because you'll need to calculate the difference of % between last print and new print, then erase a few characters backward to overwrite the `XXX %` and add the new characters, and the new %. Whereas in the other solutions, you just print a `\r` to go back at begining of the line the number of `#` and the %.

Comment: @zmo I have added some more constraints in the question i asked. That is the reason i want it within a loop

Comment: It is key to use `echo -n "$value %" $'\r'` so that the lines get rewritten. I was about to post the answer when the question was closed.

Comment: @fedorqui but that will only update the percentage, how will the number of `#` marks be updated as percentage increase.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Let's use `echo -n '...' $'\r'` to print a carriage return:

```
for ((k = 0; k <= 10 ; k++))
do
    echo -n "[ "
    for ((i = 0 ; i <= k; i++)); do echo -n "###"; done
    for ((j = i ; j <= 10 ; j++)); do echo -n "   "; done
    v=$((k * 10))
    echo -n " ] "
    echo -n "$v %" $'\r'
    sleep 0.05
done
echo
```

It makes the cursor move to the beginning of the line to keep printing.

Output is as follows, always in the same line:

```
[ ##################                ] 50 % 

.../...

[ ################################# ] 100 %
```

Comment: How does $'\r' work ? What does the $ do ? Just curious

Comment: @Jidder it returns to the beginning of the line without going to the next one. With `$` you indicate the print that specific char, not the literal `\r`.

Comment: So the same as using the -e option on echo ? Just never seen that done before. Nice answer btw.

Answer (score 7):

Using `printf`:

```
for((i=0;i<=100;i+=6)); do
    printf "%-*s" $((i+1)) '[' | tr ' ' '#'
    printf "%*s%3d%%\r"  $((101-i))  "]" "$i"
    sleep 0.1
done; echo
```

Output: (in same line.. printed on different lines here for demo.)

```
[                                                                                                   ]  0%
[######                                                                                             ]  6%
[############                                                                                       ] 12%
[##################                                                                                 ] 18%
[########################                                                                           ] 24%
[##############################                                                                     ] 30%
[####################################                                                               ] 36%
[##########################################                                                         ] 42%
[################################################                                                   ] 48%
[######################################################                                             ] 54%
[############################################################                                       ] 60%
[##################################################################                                 ] 66%
[########################################################################                           ] 72%
[##############################################################################                     ] 78%
[####################################################################################               ] 84%
[##########################################################################################         ] 90%
[################################################################################################   ] 96%
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use `pv` as the progress bar:

```
{
    for ((i = 0 ; i <= 100 ; i+=6)); do
        sleep 0.5 
        echo "B"
    done | pv -c -s 34 > /dev/null
}
```

Comment: I don't want to install any tools that don't come by default in `Ubuntu 12.04` installation.

Answer (score 1):

There is a lot of options, you may save and restore cursor position like this:

```
echo -e "\e[s 10 \e[u"
echo -e "\e[s 20 \e[u"
```

This is one of the vt100 terminal controlling commands, one of the commands in list:

http://www.cse.psu.edu/~kyusun/class/cmpen472/11f/hw/hw7/vt100ansi.htm

or just use \r to move cursor to the beginning of the line and redraw bar each time

```
echo -e "Original\rOverwrite"
```

The \r is more portable and will work across most UNIXes (unsure about MacOS)

In your example:

```
echo -n "["
for ((i = 0 ; i <= 100 ; i+=6)); do
    echo -ne "###\e[s] ($i%)\e[u"
    sleep 0.5
done
echo
```

Answer (score 1):

I liked the approach with `pv` but the previous answer on here didn't really mention how one could utilize it to display a specific progress percentage, so I came up with the following

```sh
dd if=/dev/urandom count=23 bs=1 2> /dev/null | pv -f -p -w 40 -s 100 > /dev/null
```

This will display a progress bar with 23%. With `dd` you can create a file of `23` bytes, pipe it into `pv` where we specify that the file we expect has a total size of `100`.

```
[======>                           ] 23%
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like below:

```
#!/bin/bash

func1() {
#reset
str=`printf '%*s' $1 ''|tr ' ' '#'`
echo -n "Loading Module: [ $str ] $1%Complete" $'\r'
#echo $processCounter
}

processCounter=0

while [  $processCounter -lt 100 ]; do

        #After Operation 1
        sleep 2
        let processCounter=processCounter+15
        func1 $processCounter

        #After operation 2
        sleep 2
        let processCounter=processCounter+35
        func1 $processCounter

done
```

sleep is Just to simulate the time require by application to install.

Using the above syntax You can do as below

```
#!/bin/bash
{
    #echo -n "["
    for ((i = 0 ; i <= 100 ; i+=6)); do
        sleep 1
        str=`printf '%*s' $i ''|tr ' ' '#'`
        echo -n "[ $str ] $i %Complete" $'\r'
    done
    echo -n "]"
    echo
}
```

Hope this helps!!

Answer (score 0):

Using tput commands

```
#!/bin/bash

x=0
load=''

TEST()
{

echo doin stuff


}
tput smcup

while [[ $x -lt 100  ]]; do
        TEST
        load="$load#"



         (( x = x + 1 ))
        echo "loading [" $load "] $x%"
        sleep 0.1
        if [[ $x -eq 100 ]]
        then
                echo done
                read -s LAL
        fi

        tput clear
done
tput clear
tput rmcup
```

Answer (score 0):

A `sed` based approach:

```
for((i=1;i<=100;i++)); do
    printf "[%100s] $i%%\r" | sed -r "
          s/ /#/$i;
          h;
          s/.*#//;
          x;
          s/#.*/#/;
          s/ /#/g;
          G;
          s/\n//";
     sleep 0.1
 done;echo
```

Explanation:

1. Print string "[<100 spaces here>] progress number%\r"
2. Replace i'th space with #
3. Copy to hold space
4. Split the string by # & store both parts - one in pattern space & one in hold space.
5. replace all spaces in first part by #
6. Join both the strings

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/extensionsapp/progre.sh

Create 24 percent progress: `progreSh 24`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is not a progress bar, but gives visual feedback of a long running process. It writes a period every one second at the end of a message.

```
function progress_start ()
{
   # create background process to echo a period every 1 second
   # to give feedback for long running processes
   echo -ne $1; while :; do echo -n .; sleep 1; done &
   progress_pid=$!
}
 
function progress_end ()
{
   echo -e $1;
   # silently kill the background process
   kill $progress_pid && wait $progress_pid &> /dev/null
}
```

Here is an example of usage.

```
progress_start 'Process that runs for several seconds'
sleep 7
progress_end '\nProcess complete.'
```

Result:

```
$ ./progress
Process that runs for several seconds.......
Process complete.
$
```