# Add progress in bash script without any addons

Tags: linux, bash

[Answered] The method that I went with that works and is beginner friendly, I simply added the

```
# Progress Bar

echo -n 'Progress: [--------------------]'
sleep 1     # <- Command 1
echo -ne '\rProgress: [#####---------------]'
sleep 1     # <- Command 2
echo -ne '\rProgress: [##########----------]'
sleep 1     # <- Command 3
echo -ne '\rProgress: [###############-----]'
sleep 1     # <- Command 4
echo -e '\rProgress: [####################]'
```

right before the print the end status message and it works like a charm for this situation; testing purposes and getting a feel for it. Hopefully, this helps anyone else in the future.

---

I've looked over the forums and posts but it seems as though most of them include having to install additional addons to inject a progress bar. I'm new to scripting and trying to learn and thought this would be a great addition to a simple script.

I understand how to use pv to add a progress update but it requires installation before it would work. Which is completely opposite of what I'm wanting.

Is there not a way to use the same progress bar that's built into linux when updating your system or installing applications like in the image below (for example)

[progressbar in linux](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oz8Yo.png)

And the script I'm wanting to add the simple progress bar without any additional installations for the users.

```
#!/bin/bash

###     Title:          Archive and backup script
###     Date:           16 July 2022
###     Author:         CJG
###     Version:        1.0.0


# The path of the folder you want to back up (change to folder of choice)

backup_files="/home/"

# The backup destination path (change from tmp otherwise it will be deleted upon system reboot)
dest="/tmp"

# Create a variable for the start and end times

# date command will take the current time when the now variable is called
# %H will format output to show the hour when variable is called
# %M will format output to show the minutes when variable is called
# %S will format output to show the seconds when the variable is called

now=$(date +"%H:%M:%S")

# Create the archive filename

currentDate=$(date +"%y-%m-%d")
hostname=$(hostname -s)
archive_file="$hostname-$currentDate.tgz"

# Inform that the process is starting 

echo "Backing up $backup_files to $dest/$archive_file"
echo "The process is starting."

# Print the start time 


echo Script start time: "$now"

# Back up the files using the tar command

tar -czPf $dest/$archive_file $backup_files

# Print the end status message

echo "Backup Is Complete"
now=$(date +"%H:%M:%S")
echo Script end time: "$now"
```

Comment: What makes you think that progress bar is built into Linux, rather than being provided by a library used by `apt`?

Comment: Can you create a temporary library using apt to inject a progress bar? This doesn't require any escalated privileges of any sort?

Comment: @chepner It looks like 

```
echo 'Dpkg::Progress-Fancy "1";' > /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/99progressbar
```
BUT: This wouldn't work for what I'm trying to do, correct? As it states below.

Note that the progress bar only appears when running an apt command, not an apt-get command; e.g., ‘apt update’, ‘apt upgrade’ and ‘apt install’.

Comment: a simple web search on `site:stackoverflow.com bash progress bar` brings up a slew of SO hits with quite a few answers that require no additional 'installations', eg, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/238073), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63055737), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60597755), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23630501) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41207932)

Comment: if using 'basic' bash capabilities the general idea is to have the script switch back and forth between a) doing something and b) printing/updating the status bar; this in turn is typically implemented via some sort of loop (eg, `while loop; do do_stuff; update_bar; done`; several of the links I provided (see previous comment) show this; for this particular case you could have a `find` (looking for files to add to archive) feeding a `while` loop, and within the `while` loop you a) add a file (generated by `find`) to the archive and b) update/print the status bar

Comment: if you need to implement some sort of multi-line status bar you'll likely need to incorporate something like `tput` into the mix (whether or not `tput` is already available will depend on what your sysadmin considered as part of a 'default' installation); see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59554645) for  an example using `tput` to manage a multi-line status bar

Comment: Thank you I appreciate it! I just added the simple echo'd progress bar method that you linked and it looks legit! I know it's not actually accurate to what is being done but it's a perfect start for me. 

Looking over some of the other materials is very overwhelming and I have no idea what half of it means yet.... but I'll get there one day! Thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

Yes - you can but is not as that straight forward as you think.

You can use **ANSI escape codes**

here is a really simple one

```bash
for index in {1..10}; do sleep 0.1; printf "\e[D#\e[C" ; done; echo
```

- `\e[D` move the cursor to left
- `\e[C` move the cursor to right

And the above `for` is not practical so much, because **progress bar** is an indicator for **unfinished** and usually background jobs.

Here is a better version, that prints `#` while the background jobs has not finished yet

```bash
#!/bin/bash

sleep 5 &
sleep_pid=$!;

echo PID: $sleep_pid;

while [ -e /proc/$sleep_pid ]; do
    sleep 0.1; printf "\e[D#\e[C" ;
done
echo

echo PID: $sleep_pid done
```

help

- `$!` Process ID
- `-e FILE        True if file exists.`

Please note if a task takes long time to be finished, the `while` loop prints that long time which is not desired in terms of UX. So the **speed rate** should be calculated to have a proper progress bar.